# Finding if a given position (lat, lon) is within the BoundingBox of two coordinates (route-me)

Tags: iphone, geolocation, latitude-longitude, route-me

I am working on an iPhone app using the Route-Me project.
I am using a method called 'latitudeLongitudeBoundingBoxForScreen' which returns a set of two cooördinates. Defining the Northeast and Southwest corners in lat/lon of your screen. This seems to work fine.

My question is how can I determine whether a given point (lat/lon) is within the boundaries of these two coordinates (northeast,southwest)?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For general point in a polygon, the [Point Inclusion Test](http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html) seems to work assuming a trivial Equirectanglular projection (x = lon, y = lat).

Since you know the north-east and south-west, you can compute the north-west and south-east corners.  Also, keep in mind that your bounding polygon (box) must following a winding convention (you just can't throw points at the Point Inclusion Test).

This will break if the bounding box goes across the 180 lon line.  The simple fix is if the box that crosses 180 lon line is to add 360 to the negative longitude.  This isn't a valid navigation point but it makes the math work.

This also will not work around the poles.

Comment: to handle the poles, you just need to check for lat exceeding MAX_LAT or MIN_LAT.

Comment: The problem around the poles is with the equirectangular projection.  Image a square surrounding a pole on the globe.  Now picture that bounding box projected onto a flat map.  For the poles, I would change the projection, centered at the poles.

Comment: I see what you're saying. It is just a special case you'd have to handle if the data ever got near those areas. It's definitely something to be careful of with regards to calculations, as cos(lat) is 0 at the poles, and you want to stay away from div/0.

Answer (score 0):

I know that a long time has passedby, but maybe someone still interested.

```
    Double lat_A, lat_B,lng_A, lng_B, curr_lat,curr_lng;
    LatLng nw_corner, sw_corner;
    Boolean lat_OK,lng_OK,all_OK;
    int t_segs, points;
    t_segs = segments.size()-1;
    curr_lat = curr_LatLng.latitude;
    curr_lng = curr_LatLng.longitude;
    lat_A = list_segm_points.get(0).latitude;
    lng_A = list_segm_points.get(0).longitude;
    lat_B = list_segm_points.get(t_segs).latitude;
    lng_B = list_segm_points.get(t_segs).longitude;

    if (lat_A > lat_B ) {
        lat_OK = curr_lat < lat_A && curr_lat > lat_B;
    } else {
        lat_OK = curr_lat > lat_A && curr_lat < lat_B;
    }
    if (lng_A > lng_B ) {
        lng_OK = curr_lng < lng_A && curr_lng > lng_B;
    } else {
        lng_OK = curr_lng > lng_A && curr_lng < lng_B;
    }
    all_OK = lat_OK && lng_OK;
    return all_OK;
```