# How determine if point is within rectangle given all latitude/longitude coordinates?

Tags: gps, latitude-longitude, rectangles

If given x/y coordinates for all 4 corners of rectangle, and then another x/y, it's easy to determine if the point is within the rectangle if top left is 0,0.

But what if the coordinates are latitude/longitude where they can be negative (please see attached). Is there a formula that can work in this case?

[image]

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6664069/817828

Answer (score 3):

Mathematicaly, you could use inequations to determine that.

edit: When doing the example, i've noticed you put the coordinates in the inverse format (y,x) instead of (x,y). In my example I use (x,y) format, so I just inverted the order to easy my explanation.

Let's say 
A = (-130,10)
B = (-100,20)
C = (-125,-5)
D = (-100,5)

You build an inequation from your rectangle edges :

```
if( (x,y) < AB && (x,y) > AC && (x,y) > CD && (x,y) < BD) then
    (x,y) belongs to rectangle ABCD
end if
```

If all inequations are true, then your point belongs to the rectangle

---

Concrete example :

AB represent the segment but can be represented by a formula : y = ax + b

to determine a (the slope of the formula, not the point A) you get the difference of

```
(Ay - By) / (Ax - Bx)
```

Ay means Y component of point A wich is 10 in that case

That formula gives us

```
(10 - 20) / (-130 - -100) = -10 / -30 = 1/3
```

Now we have

```
y = x/3 + b
```

We now determine b. We now that both point A and B belongs to that formula. So we take any of them to replace the x,y values in the formula. Let's take point B :

```
20 = -100/3 + b
```

We isolate b giving us :

```
b = -100 / 60 = -10/6
```

We have now

```
y = x/3 - (6/10)
```

So if we want to determine if Point Z (10, 15) belongs to your retangle, you check firstly if

```
y > x/3 - (10/6)
```

Then in the case of Z(10, 15) :

```
15 > 10/3 - (10/6)

15 > 10/6

15 > 1.66 is true
```

So condition is met for this edge. You need to this same logic for each edges.

Note that to determine if you use > or <, you need to tell if at a certain x value, our point has a bigger y or smaller y value than our rectangle edge.

You can use < and > if you want a point to be strictly inside the rectangle; <= and >= if a point on the rectangle's edge belongs to the rectangle too. You decide.

I hope that my explanation is clear. Feel free to ask more if some points are unclear.

Comment: I've added a concrete example to my answer. Hope it will help you out.

Comment: Ok it looked easy, but now i know, that the generall point in polygon solution is not difficulter than this.

Comment: Yeah, in this situation it is a rectangle, but you could easily do it for a polygon having an Array of polygon segments to verify.

Comment: Yes and the general case for a polygon is well known, optimaly solved with existing source code. See link above